# WorldToGUIPoint seems always off by about 2 pixels

Tags: unity, gui

I'm trying to draw small boxes at each vertex of a mesh, in the editor. My OnSceneGUI code looks like this:

```
foreach (Vector3 vertex in _mesh.vertices) {
    Vector3 worldVertex = _meshTransform.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertex);
    Vector2 guiPoint = HandleUtility.WorldToGUIPoint(worldVertex);
    var rect = new Rect(guiPoint, Vector2.one * BOX_SIZE);
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(rect, Color.red);
}
```

I want the upper-left corner of each box to align with the mesh vertices. With the above code, the boxes are drawn at the wrong location, as you can see in the picture below. If I apply an offset of (2, -2) in GUI coordinates, however, the boxes are drawn at the correct location.

I'd like to avoid having to hard-code this (2, -2) offset into each draw call. Why is Unity off by a few pixels here? I also tried using `GUI.Box` to do the drawing, but it was off by the same amount. What is going on?

**Incorrect**
[image: Incorrect]

**Correct. With constant (2, -2) offset**
[image: Correct]

**Update:** I have an untested hypothesis as to why this is happening. I am rendering a GUI rect with the default `GUIStyle`. The default `GUIStyle` has the `padding` and `margin` values set. I bet that if I created a custom `GUIStyle` with zero `padding` and `margin` the rects would draw where I want them to.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the 2 pixel displacement , but try putting the camera in orthographic projection this might fix the problem.

Comment: The only camera is the editor camera. It is already in 2D mode

Comment: Can you share the whole script ?? I'll try it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The `GUI` and `EditorGUI` drawing functions seem to not be the best solution for the level of drawing precision that I need. They seem to be influenced by `GUIStyle`, which has dozens of properties that may interfere with positioning. The better solution I found was to use `GL` combined with the built-in shader `Hidden/Internal-Colored` to get the screen-space positioning that I wanted:

```
    var shader = Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored");
    var material = new Material(shader);
    material.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
    material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0); // Don't write to depth buffer
    material.SetInt("_ZTest",  (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.CompareFunction.Always); // Always draw on top of other elements
    material.SetPass(0);

    GL.PushMatrix();

    GL.LoadPixelMatrix();
    GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
    GL.Color(Color.red);

    // For each vertex, convert it to screen-space with
    // Camera.current.WorldToScreenPoint, then use
    // GL.Vertex3 to draw a quad around it

    GL.End();

    GL.PopMatrix();
```